# React Navigation Is there a way to refer to a navigator from the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I understand that navigation and route props are automatically passed to the target screen when you navigate. So you can access navigation when you're in that screen, say screen B.

What I want to do is in Screen A, where the navigator is defined, I'd like to be able to setParams every so often. How can I refer to the navigator in this case?

For example, I would like to do this:

`navigator.screen('posts').setParams({videoData: stuff});`

A.js

```
const A = () => {
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
  const navigator =   <Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="posts" component={FeedList} />
  </Tab.Navigator>;

  useEffect(()=> {
    fetchStuff((stuff)=> {
      navigator.screen('posts').setParams({videoData: dataState});
    });
  },[]);

  return <>{navigator}</>;
}
```

Inside the useEffect, I ideally would be able to dynamically set the route params of the target screen.

I tried using initialParams and a state, but the initialParams doesn't seem to update in the target screen when the state changes. (So, I would accept that as an answer too, if you know why that's not working.)

not working initialParams example:

```
const A = () => {
  const [dataState, setDataState] = useState(null);
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  useEffect(()=> {
    fetchStuff((stuff)=> {
      setDataState(stuff);  // this doesn't seem to update initialParams
    });
  },[]);

  return <Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="posts" component={FeedList} initialParams={{videoData: dataState}} />
  </Tab.Navigator>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#setparams) function.

Here is the code of updating of the state of a nested tab's screen after 3 seconds.

```
import React, {useContext, useState, createContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const KeyContext = createContext();
const DELAY_TIME = 3000;

const KeyContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [routeKey, setRouteKey] = useState(null);
  return (
    <KeyContext.Provider
      value={{key: routeKey, setKey: (value) => setRouteKey(value)}}>
      {props.children}
    </KeyContext.Provider>
  );
};

const AScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const {key} = useContext(KeyContext);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (key) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigation.dispatch({
          ...CommonActions.setParams({value: 'Updated state'}),
          source: key,
        });
      }, DELAY_TIME);
    }
  }, [navigation, key]);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="screen B"
        component={BScreen}
        initialParams={{value: 'Initial state'}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="screen C" component={CScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const BScreen = ({route}) => {
  const val = route.params?.value || null;
  const {setKey} = useContext(KeyContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setKey(route.key);
  }, [route, setKey]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>Screen B</Text>
      <Text>{val}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const CScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>Screen C</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <KeyContextProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Screen A" component={AScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </KeyContextProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'},
});
```

Comment: what's the difference between doing `navigation.dispatch(...CommonActions.setParams(...))` compared to just `navigation.setParams`

Comment: ive tested some more, this doesn't seem to work if you have more than two copies of BScreen. The only ones that get updated are the first screen and the last screen.

Comment: The implementation I did keeps track of the route key of only one screen. You need to make sure you have access to and use the right key value of all the screens meaning using a different context data structure such as array.